# IonSlides render something on lastSLide. Ionic React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to dynamically show my buttons when i get to the lastSlide, but it dies not seems to work.

I'm trying to use FindIndex to find someText that is actually on the lastSlide and nothing happens

The console prints out `4` because i have `5` items in the Array which is correct, but i can't render something to the dom

if there's any other options in the `IonSlides Component` itself, i will appreciate, because `onSlideReachEnd` event that `ionic` provides does not work.

```
  const lastIndex = slideContent.findIndex((element) => {
    if (element.slideTitle === "Safe & Secure") {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  console.log(lastIndex); // 4

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <div className="content">
        <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts}>
          {slideContent.map((slide, idx) => (
            <IonSlide key={idx}>
              <div>
                <img
                  src={slide.slideImage}
                  alt={slide.slideAltText}
                  className={slide.slideClassName}
                />
                <IonText>
                  <h5 className="mb-1 fw-bold">{slide.slideTitle}</h5>
                </IonText>
                <IonText color="primary" className="fw-bold">
                  <h4 className="mt-0 bold h4"> {slide.slidePrimaryText} </h4>
                </IonText>
                <div className="pt-0 px-5 pb-4">
                  <IonText>
                    <h6 className="fs-md mb-6 line-h fw-sm fw-reg tet-color">
                      {slide.slideText}
                      {slide.slideSecoundaryText && (
                        <IonText color="primary" className="fw-bold ">
                          <h6 className="mt-0 fs-md bold mt-3">
                            {slide.slideSecondaryText}
                          </h6>
                        </IonText>
                      )}
                    </h6>
                  </IonText>

                  {slide.slideBtn && (
                    <IonButton
                      shape="round"
                      fill="clear"
                      className="btn f-inherit"
                      size="small"
                    >
                      Stuff
                    </IonButton>
                  )}

                  {idx}
                </div>
              </div>
            </IonSlide>
          ))}
        </IonSlides>
      </div>

      {lastIndex && (
        <div className="ion-padding">
          <IonGrid>
            <IonRow>
              <IonCol size="6">
                <IonButton
                  expand="block"
                  className="btn"
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() => navigate("/login", "forward")}
                >
                  Login
                </IonButton>
              </IonCol>
              <IonCol size="6">
                <IonButton
                  expand="block"
                  fill="outline"
                  onClick={() => navigate("/get-started", "forward")}
                  className="btn"
                  size="small"
                >
                  Get Started
                </IonButton>
              </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
          </IonGrid>
        </div>
      )}
    </IonPage>
```

);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const SlidePage = () => {
  const [isLastSlide, setIsLastSlide] = useState();

  const slideChanged = async e => {
    const r = await e.target.isEnd();
    setIsLastSlide(r);
    console.log("isEnd", r);
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonSlides pager={true} onIonSlideDidChange={slideChanged}>
          <IonSlide>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          </IonSlide>
          <IonSlide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          </IonSlide>
          <IonSlide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          </IonSlide>
        </IonSlides>
        {isLastSlide && <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>IS LAST SLIDE</h1>}
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
```

listen for slide change event and update the state if it is the last slide.

[onIonSlideDidChange](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides)

working example here on stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w5gawb?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Worked like charm